# LVP "Wood" Flooring Hard to Clean

Tags: flooring, laminate-floor

We just bought a new home that has LVP flooring to mimic wood floors. It has wood like grain, like you'd see on dry barnwood, and it is impossible to clean out the grooves. We live in Georgia so our yard is 90% red clay that pretty much glows on these stupid floors and gets stuck in every nook and cranny. We tried the no shoes rule, but I have three boys... Enough said. Is there some type of "sealer" or anything that can fill in the grooves to make the flooring smooth? I tried looking up products, but they're just all over the place.

Comment: You may just have to replace the whole floor with continuous vinyl or tile depending on your budget.

Comment: Sounds like the flooring was not installed correctly.  When done correct, there are no grooves for dirt to get into.  If the flooring has the "seam" look of some woods, LVP should still be locked together tightly enough that dirt does not have anything to get into.  I have LVP in all of my rental properties and the tenants all praise how easy it is to clean with a hard floor vac or swiffer.  Pics of the floor may help determine if it was done right.

Comment: @RMDman I have flooring similar to what the OP describes in one of the rooms in my house (and I have plans to replace it because I hate it). The 'grooves' between each 'board' are a part of the design - each board's top edges edges are chamfered by maybe about 1/16" (or a little less), resulting in a groove around each board. It's an intentional design choice by the manufacturer, and an absolute PitA to keep clean.